# The history of italics for emphasis

Tags: manuscripts, fonts

For printed texts I understand that italics is often used for emphasis.
For traditional handwriting, is/was it also a common practise to do the same?

If not, what is the history behind this innovation in printing?

Comment: Wikipedia has a history section on its page on italics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italic_type

Comment: @Erk The page mentions italics for emphasis began in the sixteenth century, but it doesn't say how. I'm wondering whether it started in manuscripts.

Comment: You might ask History SE this question and get a better, more detailed response.